# Push notification not working in Amazon SNS

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, amazon-sns

I am using Amazon AWS Mobile Hub in my app. I have configured the push notification feature. In the sample app provided by AWS the push notification registration is also successful. I can check the end point and subscription data in SNS portal.
But if I publish any message its not displaying in my App. Also in my Google Project the GCM data is nil.

Answer (score 1):

While creating a project in Google API for GCM it provides a project name and an ID number.

I was submitting the name in Amazon AWS but it should be the ID number.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned GCM, so I'm assuming you're on Android. Are you using an AVD image in the Android Emulator or on an actual device?

How are you sending the push message? If you're using the Amazon SNS console, you can select the topic and push a message with Raw type and just put "Test" in the payload and it should show up.

One thing to check is that your device is not on a corporate or other VPN network which restricts any network access in its firewall rules. I know GCM push does not work consistently on our internal corporate LAN because of such firewall rules.